# CakePHPで外部ライブラリと自作のライブラリを保管するディレクトリについて

Tags: cakephp

CakePHPで外部ライブラリを設置するディレクトリは通常Vendorですが
今ここにはcomposer経由でインストールしたライブラリを置いています。

そのためVendorはgitignoreにしているのですがそうすると
gitで管理したい自作ライブラリをVendorに置くことができません。

このようなシーンでは皆様どのように対応されているのでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

アプリケーション独自で利用する自作ライブラリは、`app/Lib/`に配置します。

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/ja/getting-started/cakephp-folder-structure.html#app

CakePHPに依存するライブラリであれば、上記場所に設置するのが良いでしょう。

CakePHPに依存しない自作ライブラリは、Composer管理でVender配下に配置したほうがよいと考えます。

composerでrequire時に`--prefer-source`オプションを付与することで、バージョン管理システムの情報を含めてダウンロードできますので、ライブラリの開発も同時に行う場合はこれを利用します。なお、composerはrepositories指定で、packagist経由ではなく内部gitレポジトリ経由で取得もできます。